# Building pipenv with requirements file on Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pipenv

I am having a big trouble building my dockerised version of flask app.
At first I am not able to install any dependencies from requirements.txt file which is provided inside the container itself. Here is a folder structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── ASRModule.py
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── config
│   ├── files
│   ├── index.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Interval.py
│   ├── MySQLDBHandler.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── SIPCall.py
│   ├── SOAPClient.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── stats.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── TrunkOccupation.py
│   └── TrunkTraffic.py
├── Dockerfile
├── instance
└── requirements.txt
```

And my Dockerfile on which I want to build a containter:

```
FROM python:3.5.2-alpine

COPY . /flask
WORKDIR /flask

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

CMD ["pipenv", "shell", "testshell"]
CMD ["pipenv","install", "-r ./requirements.txt"]
```

To my understanding, after completed build I should have same folder structure except one above directory called *flask* which will hold all aforementioned files and dirs. I also should have a virtualenv called *testshell* to which all dependencies from requirements.txt should be installed. And up until now everything works silky-smooth-fine.
To my disappointment, though, after I try to run this container I see a correctly build virtual-env and such error:

> Requirements file doesn't appear to exist. Please ensure the file exists in your project directory or you provided the correct path.

I tried various paths for the requirements file but nothing helped.
I would appreciate any help which will point me, where I am making mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is rather simple, but made hard to notice by the **bad** error message - it does not say *which* file it is trying to load. The file it *tries* to load is `'/flask/ ./requirements.txt'`, i.e. `requirements.txt` in a subdirectory named *<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>* - c.f. with the error message from `pip`:

```
% "pip" "install" "-r ./requirements.txt"
Could not open requirements file: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' ./requirements.txt'
```

---

The fix is to *either* remove the space, or correctly split the arguments:

```
CMD ["pipenv", "install", "-r./requirements.txt"]
```

or

```
CMD ["pipenv", "install", "-r", "./requirements.txt"]
```

both ought to work.

---

I suggest that you will complain about the bad error message to the [pipenv issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/new/choose).